# Compiling C++ repl May 2020

Tags: c++, github, repository, replit

Compiling C++ repl

I wonder whether you can help.

I am working through the FreeCodeCamp tutorial on C++ and I am using repl.it as an online IDE.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-c-plus-plus-programming-language/

- The "+new repl" command and choosing a langauage C++ works just fine.

Since I wanted to create a Repl linked to a Github repo, which I thought migth be a good thing to keep both up-to-date, it seems it autocreates a ".replit" file alongside the main.cpp file. The default .replit file which contains two lines:

```
language="cpp" 
run=""
```

Which won't compile and the error is:

```
'run' isn't configured in the .replit file try adding 'run = "echo
hello word"' to .replit
```

I read this: "Configuring the run button / .replit" in the Docs section
https://docs.repl.it/repls/dot-replit

I went back to creating a new Repl, looking at the output when it's run successfully (a new C++ Repl, unlinked to Github, trying to guess what's the default run="" for a C++ Repl), then copied a line from the terminal output and made my .replit file look like this (clang being the compiler, it seems, the rest - some necessary parameters). I haven't researched each of the parameter, so I apologise in advance.

```
run="clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp"
language="cpp"
```

The result is but I was expecting a Hello World print out which normally works, if I'd use a +new Repl:

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
```

*A screenshot from Repl.it tryingt to compile a new C++ Repl* :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It works for me. Please share the code by clicking Share > Copy the Share Link, then paste the link into your original question so we can better help you

Comment: Thanks @pctopgs - I have the github repo actually here - [link] (https://repl.it/@atanas/Round-C-2020-Google-KickStart#main.cpp) or perhaps it's [invite link] (https://repl.it/join/pnvuekui-atanas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the .replit file on the and see if that resolves your problem.
Check this image for reference: [Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUNml.png)